# Search for list of words in body using simple

Tags: apache-camel

Is it possible to specify a variable list of words to check if they exist in body using `simple`? Something similar to:

```
simple("${in.header.type} in 'gold,silver'")
```

But using `"contains"` to search in

```
${in.body} (Camel 2.32.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Contains` works with only one string at a time. To search for a list of strings in the body you can implement a processor to do so.